# How can the cost function dimensionality be understood?

Tags: error, multivariate-regression

[Most tutorials on the internet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OvhLPS7rj4&t=3s) demonstrate the cost function with the `m * x + b = y` function,
which is fine and understandable for a start..

They presents the concepts in a very approachable way, with 1 input and 1 output.
However I fail to understand to interpret this in higher dimensions.

In case the feature array is of higher dimensions, to calculate the error, the same 1 dimensional cost 
can be calculated to the features separately, may it be MSE, Cross entropy or whatever.

In the end most libraries produce a single scalar number, as the overall error for a given network, and I fail to understand how that number is produced from a vector of errors.

Are my assumptions even correct? If they are, I would believe the errors are simply sumed up from each of the feature-errors. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "each of the feature-errors"?  How is an error associated with any individual feature rather than with the prediction itself?

Comment: Suppose we have a 3 dimensional regression prediction. In case only one sample, the feature-array is the array of 3 outputs of the Neural network. For each element in the network output there will be an error value. With MSE for each network output, the error for that output is the squared mean difference from the expected value. What I cannot understand is, how can I interpret the error not for one "output", but for the whole array of outputs; i.e.: how to calculate a scalar value (whole feature error) from the 3 dimensional data ( 3 errors of the induvidual features ) .

Comment: Thank you.  We tend to think of this as a *multivariate* (prediction) problem: by "features" you are referring not to the predictor (or explanatory) variables, but to the response variables.  If that interpretation is correct, consider applying related tags, such as [tag:multivariate-regression].

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and excuse my lingo, I'm scraping this together from various places from the internet.